# Pinta Keeps Crashing -

Tags: 20.04, pinta

Pinta keeps crashing on 20.04.2 LTS. I have done what is said on this page here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/1786822.
A lot of people say updating the monorepos will fix it, like it says here: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin
For me, that didn't help.

Here is the Terminal log when I run `pinta`

```
pinta
double free or corruption (out)

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x564f3ec26eb5 - /usr/bin/mono : (null)
    0x564f3ec27250 - /usr/bin/mono : (null)
    0x564f3ebd4129 - /usr/bin/mono : (null)
    0x564f3ec26467 - /usr/bin/mono : (null)
    0x7fb1664943c0 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 : (null)
    0x7fb1662b818b - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : gsignal
    0x7fb166297859 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : abort
    0x7fb1663023ee - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : (null)
    0x7fb16630a47c - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : (null)
    0x7fb16630c120 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : (null)
    0x40f82db3 - Unknown

=================================================================
    Telemetry Dumper:
=================================================================
Killed
```

Please let me know if there is something I can do, or if I need to post more information?

Comment: Can you try to install [Pinta 2.0](https://www.pinta-project.com/releases/2-0)? This was a major release in December 2021 porting the code to GTK3. I was able to run it on Ubuntu budgie, which is a downstream of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (focal), after installing the missing dependencies `xdg-desktop-portal` and `appmenu-gtk3-module`. With plain LTS Ubuntu and Gnome, Pinta 2.0 should run anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apt update
apt install gtk-sharp2
apt install mono-devel
```

Ubuntu 20.04 & Ubuntu 22.04 tested and works fines :)